# Unable to use gitpython ImportError

Tags: python-3.x, git

Tried to run a script I wrote yesterday again today and ran into this:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Repo' from 'git' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/git/__init__.py)
```

I am at a complete loss.  On a new computer so the only thing different install wise would have been that I installed pycharm.  I am currently trying to run through bash shell on a mac. The exact code was running as excepted earlier, no code changes.

Things I have tried:

- uninstalling/reinstalling python
- uninstalling/reinstalling pip
- uninstalling/reinstalling gitpython

Running on:

- mac catalina
- python version 3.7.6
- pip version 20.0.1

As a side note, the script works as intended until the automated git push.  Wondering if I should just make the os calls myself and not worry about this?

I really dont understand what I did/am doing wrong here.

EDIT:

Again, sorry as this is my first mac computer.  I did a brew uninstall of python3 and reinstalled through the app store to 3.8.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_cygwin_git' from partially initialized module 'git.util' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/
```

I know cygwin is for windows, but I figured I'd play along and trying a pip install pycygwin.

Install threw an error asking for cython, so I did another pip install and tried again.  The pycygwin then complained gcc was missing so I did a brew install of gcc. With gcc installed and correctly on path, it still says it cant find it and exits with

```
    build/cygwin/_cygwin.c:611:10: fatal error: 'sys/cygwin.h' file not found
    #include <sys/cygwin.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Thinking I might just try a different package manager? Currently, an attempt to rerun the script yeilds

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Repo' from partially initialized module 'git' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

To which I investigated but I shouldn't have any overlapping dependancies.
On the script throwing the error I'm using:

- import csv
- import yaml
- import os
- from git import Repo

and on the wrapper I made and imported, I'm using:

- import subprocess
- import re

Will update if I get any further on this, would love some suggestions.

EDIT:

Importing using just import git works throws a different error, like the python is trying to get itself?

```
ImportError: cannot import name '<file name>' from '<file name>'
```

If I change the file name and try to run it, it comes backs with:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '<old file name>' from '<old file name>'
```

***FIXED****

1. Uninstall of python through homebrew
2. Reinstall of python through mac app store
3. Uninstall/Reinstall of modules through pip
4. Saving the file under a new name and deleting the old one

Still have absolutely no idea why/how this happened but the above worked for me.  If anyone knows why something like this can happen, I would love to know. Cheers.